# Android custom seekBar with "stations"

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm trying to make my custom seekbar. 
This is what i try to do:

 [image]

and this is what I succeed to do:

 [image]

How to add this circles behind my progress?

Here is my code:

```
<SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/unnamed"
        android:id="@+id/risk_seek_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

background fill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FF555555"
        android:endColor="#FF555555"
        android:startColor="#FF555555" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

progress_fill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FFFF4400"
        android:endColor="#FFFF4400"
        android:startColor="#FFFF4400" />



    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

Comment: The no. of stations are static as in do they change or remain the same always ?

Comment: they can change,but it less important for me right now just need some way to put a circles behind the progress

Comment: What's your minimum SDK version number for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following libraries

[range-slider-view](https://github.com/channguyen/range-slider-view)

[material-range-bar](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar)

[range-bar](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar)